Azure Release Pipeline replacing my $ instead use as literal
I have an asp.net core app that has an empty connection for the production environment.
My goal is to change it during the deployment using Azure Library secrets.
My release pipeline calls this method here:
ssh devops@server /usr/bin/docker run -p80:80 --name container1 --network open -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=PRD -e ConnectionStrings:my-db="User Id=USERX;Password=$(UserXPassword)');Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostora)(PORT=1520))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))" -d register:5000/imagem01:1

This doesn't work because the value of $(UserXPassword) inside my Azure Library has a $ in the middle of it, Ex: Pas$word!Now
The pipeline returns Pas!Now (replacing $word for nothing, because it is understood as a Linux variable).
We tried almost everything, trying ' around variables and " too. The only thing that works until now is using my password at Azure Library with Pas\$word!Now.
If I use \$ instead of $ on the password, it works, but I don't believe it's reasonable.
Can anyone explain to me what am I missing?
EDIT
Here comes my task:
steps:
- script: |
   ssh devops@server /usr/bin/docker image pull register:5000/container01:$(Release.ReleaseName)
   ssh devops@server /usr/bin/docker container stop container01
   ssh devops@server /usr/bin/docker rm -f container01 || true
   ssh devops@server '/usr/bin/docker run -p80:80 --name container01 --network opened -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=PRD -e ConnectionStrings:my-db=$(ConnectionString) -d register:5000/container01:$(Release.ReleaseName)'
   ssh devops@server /usr/bin/docker image prune -fa || true
  displayName: 'Run container'
  env:
    ConnectionString: $(MY_LIBRARY_CONNSTRING)


Can you please share the azure pipeline task where the command is being run?  Have you considered setting environment variables at the task level for the connection string, etc and then using these variables in the command instead of the variable group values?

The command is what I put as code in my question. I just masked the server name and this kind of stuff.
I'm using a self-hosted agent running on my VM. It calls this SSH to another VM with the containers and runs the command I show here.
Do you want to see the Azure pipeline task of the Azure Site?

Yes it might be helpful to see the full task where you run the ssh devops@server /usr/bin/docker run ... command.

This is off-topic on SO

@Vega aren't Docker or CI-CD pipelines considered "software tools commonly used by programmers", as mentioned in What topics can I ask about here?? I'm starting to get confused about what is off-topic or not.

May i know if you use hardcode connection string (Pas$word!Now, not any variable) in the command ssh devops@server ..., does it work? In addition, if you echo $(secretvar), it will show **** as expected. You can echo $(connectionstring) > test.txt, and publish the txt in artifact, download it to confirm the string value.

I did not try a hardcoded password in my command. I will try it.

@LeandroDeMelloFagundes any updates on this? Have you tried an hardcoded password? Also, consider using a dummy variable group (library) with a variable that is NOT set as a secret - this way you can see its value in the pipeline logs and ensure that is being retrieved correctly (as mentioned in my answer).

To avoid similar issues without having to escape special characters such as $ consider setting environment variables at the task level, instead of using pipeline variables (e.g. from variable groups) directly in the scripts.
Example
Consider the following variable group with variable my_connection_string:

Using the pipeline variable directly in the script:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - group: group1

steps:
- bash: |
    echo "Connection string: $(my_connection_string)"
  displayName: 'Show connection string using pipeline variable'

Running the pipeline:

Setting and using the environment variable at the task level:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - group: group1

- bash: |
    echo "Connection string: $CONNECTION_STRING"
  displayName: 'Show connection string using environment variable'
  env: 
    CONNECTION_STRING: $(my_connection_string) # set environment variable from pipeline variable

Running the pipeline:

Notes:

Environment variables might not be expanded when using single quotes such as 'echo $MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE'. Use double-quotes instead: "echo $MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE".
Syntax for referencing environment variables might change, depending on the operating system (Linux, Windows) or the type of pipeline task (script, bash, pwsh, ...): $MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE, ${MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}, ${Env:MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE} (Powershell), %MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE%, etc


I edited my question with my task and followed your example, but it didn't work.

@LeandroDeMelloFagundes you're not using the right syntax for the environment variables. ConnectionString is not a pipeline variable, so remove the parenthesis. Try ConnectionStrings:my-db=$ConnectionString instead of ConnectionStrings:my-db=$(ConnectionString).

Unfortunately, we tried :( Didn't work. I believe there is something else I'm missing right now.

@LeandroDeMelloFagundes is there any error message? Are you using Windows or Linux-based build agents?

@LeandroDeMelloFagundes try wrapping the command in double-quotes "/usr/bin/docker run ..." instead of single-quotes '/usr/bin/docker run ...', otherwise the environment variable(s) won't be expanded/resolved. Also, add a dummy task that echoes the variable(s) to check if it's working or not before trying to run the docker commands.

the Echo does not work because the password is inside a secret variable. It shows me **** instead the password. I'll try the double quotes.

@LeandroDeMelloFagundes keep in mind that the syntax for referencing environment variables might change - see my last edit.

I'm running a release in Azure DevOps. The release has a Library Var.
The release has steps, and one of the steps has a task. The task is a script task shooting ssh commands (because the release runs over my Azure self-hosted agent) to the docker server. The command is a docker run passing a -e ConnectionString through changing my connection string during deployment. The value of the connection string is inside my Library Var.

@LeandroDeMelloFagundes what exact problem do you have at the moment? Is there any error message? Are you using Windows or Linux-based build agents?

Take another good look into all the details in my question (syntax, quotes, etc) and read the comments again, to ensure you didn't miss anything. Also, create a dummy variable group (library) with a test variable that is NOT set as a secret and echo it, to see if it is displayed properly in the logs. Please share some details about what you've tried so far and what happened.
